# How to subscribe views in a custom Adapter for a single button action

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

I'm making an app that can start/stop multiple chronometers shown in a ListView. The user is able to start/stop the chronometers individually but I also need a button that Start/stops all of them at the same time.
I don't want to traverse each chronometer individually in a for structure since it would make the chronometers start/stop with time delays.

My CustomAdapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

int numberChronometers;
private Context context;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int numberChronometers)
{
    this.numberChronometers = numberChronometers;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return numberChronometers;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater =
                (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chronometer_layout, null);
    }

    final TextView textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_chronometer);
    ToggleButton toggleButton =
            (ToggleButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_start_stop_single);
    final Button resetButton = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_reset_single);

    textView.setText("0");
    toggleButton.setChecked(false);
    toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked)
            {
                // Toggle is enabled
                textView.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.start));
                resetButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else
            {
                // Toggle is disabled
                textView.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.stop));
                resetButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    });
    resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textView.setText("0");
        }
    });


    return convertView;
}
}
```

My chronometer_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="5">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_chronometer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:text="0"/>
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/button_start_stop_single"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textOn="@string/stop"
    android:textOff="@string/start" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_reset_single"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/reset"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

My main activity is just a ListActivity with a button for Start/Stop, a reset button and the ListView for the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

To get away from iterating through each chronometer individually, you could look at [Otto EventBus](http://square.github.io/otto/). That will send out a broadcast to all listeners. I am not sure, but I THINK this will make all subscribers trigger at the same time. I would be interested in seeing the difference in milliseconds between each if there is any.

If you used [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/), your code will go something like so:

Inside the `OnClickListener` that will reset all chronometers

```
bus.post(new ResetEveroneEvent());
```

Then, in each of your chronometers:

```
 @Subscribe
 public void onResetEveryoneEvent(ResetEveryoneEvent event){
      //reset this chronometer here
 }
```

*Things to Note:*

- An event is an object you create. You can call it whatever you want, and contain anything you like. The object can even be empty. In your case here, the `resetEveryoneEvent` is just an empty object because you don't need to pass any data.
- When subscribing (`@Subscribe`) the method name does not matter. Only the parameters. *Must be* `public void` No need to explicitly call this method either. It will seem it is unused.
- In any class that has `@Subscribe` annotations, you need to call `Bus.register(this);` so it knows to subscribe.
- Bus is sending out a broadcast. So it is not listeners like an onClick. Broadcast is a lower level in android, so it can be thread-safe.
- Otto will not traverse the class hierarchy and add methods from base classes or interfaces that are annotated. Meaning, if you are using bus in a class, then extend that class, Otto will stop working on that parent.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will try soon and check then :D

Answer (score 0):

In ListView there is the view that corresponds to the visual appearance of a row and there is the data that feeds information to the rows. In your code above, this data is the Object returned by getItem() and I assume this is the Chronometer object.

That said, if you want all your Chronometers to stop and start and the same time then simply assign a same value for all of them. For example to set start time for all chronometers:

```
class Chronometer{
      long millisStart;
}
```

then just do so in your startAll button

```
private void startAll(
 long startMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); //same time for everyone
   for (int i=0; i<adapter.getCount(); i++){
     Chronometer c = (Chronometer)adapter.getItem(i);
     c.millisStart = startMillis;
   } 
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
)
```

whereas what you are probably doing is

```
private void startAll(
   for (int i=0; i<adapter.getCount(); i++){
     Chronometer c = (Chronometer)adapter.getItem(i);
     c.millisStart = System.currentTimeMillis(); // delay for everyone 
   } 
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
)
```

The key is to have a common attribute that is shared among all your data objects.